Debugging the recursion couldn't solve my Issue
I wrote this function below in Python and I am expecting to see 4 as the result but get 2. Why is that?
Here is my function:
def persistence(n):
    if 0 <= n <= 9:
        return n
    else:
        result = 0
        counter = 0
        while True:
            result += n % 10 * persistence(n // 10)
            counter += 1
            if result > 9:
                n = result
                result = 0
                continue
            return counter

print(persistence(999))  # Output should be 4 but gives me 2

The goal of the function is to calculate how many times to multiply the digits of the number until you get to a one digit number.
For example:
when given n = 999 I want the process below to happen:
// 999 -> 9 * 9 * 9 = 729
// 729 -> 7 *2 *9 = 126
// 126 -> 1 *2 *6 = 12
// 12 -> 1 * 2 = 2

See? It takes four iterations to get from 999 to 2 which is a single digit number. So I want my function to return 4 which is the number of iterations to get to a one digit number but returns 2 which is not what I have expected.
I know where the problem exactly happens. It is in the line in which I wrote result += n % 10 * persistence(n // 10). when I debug it in the first iteration, instead of giving me the number 729 (the multiplication of 9 * 9 * 9) it gives me 18. Why is that? What is wrong with my code that instead of getting 729 as the output for result in the first iteration I get 18 and therefore the value of persistence(999) is not what I expect it to be?

What is the function supposed to do?

@interjay edited the body of my question. Se if you can understand it now please

So persistence(99) should be 2? In that case, you can't expect n % 10 * persistence(n // 10) to be 999 for n==999. You're expecting persistence to perform two different actions.

@interjay No. persistence(999) should be 4

I wrote 99, not 999.

@interjay Please elaborate a little bit more. Explain in more details please

If persistence(99) is 2 then 999 % 10 * persistence(999 // 10) is 9 * 2.

@interjay So. In that case with the code I have written, persistence(99) should return 81 not 2. So where is the problem in the code that I have written that instead of getting 81, I am getting 2?

You're expecting the same function to do two different jobs. Returning 81 wouldn't make sense because then persistence would just multiply the digits, which you don't want. This is just not a good way to use recursion because calculating persistence(99) doesn't help you to calculate persistence(999).

I would recommend splitting the function into two: One function product takes a number and multiplies all of its digits. Another function persistence takes a number and calls product as many times as necessary, counting the number of times and returning that result. That should help reduce the confusion as to what is actually going on.

@ndim Yes there are different solutions to this. But I want to know where exactly lies the problem in the code that I have written? I want someone to exactly point out the problem in my code and explain it in details

It's unclear, what your function is supposed to do, as commented.
My best guess is that you want to multiply the digits of a number.

In that case, you either use recursion without a while or just iterate using a loop.

def persistence(n):
    counter = 0
    result = 1
    while n:
        last_digit = n % 10
        result *= last_digit
        n //= 10
        counter += 1

    print(result)
    return counter


print(persistence(999))
print(persistence(9999))


Prints
729
3
6561
4



Notes:

The return counter in your code is inside the while loop. That's probability not what you had in mind.

When you write your base case in a recursive functiono, you no longer have to define an else.



Edit
If you want to count the number of operations until reaching one digit, we only add a few conditions:
def persistence(n):
    if -10 < n < 10:
        return 0
    if n < 0:
        n *= -1
    counter = 0
    result = 1
    while n > 9:
        last_digit = n % 10
        result *= last_digit
        n //= 10
        counter += 1

    return counter


print(persistence(999))
print(persistence(9999))
print(persistence(123456))
print(persistence(1))

print(persistence(-999))
print(persistence(-9999))
print(persistence(-123456))
print(persistence(-1))


Prints
2
3
5
0
2
3
5
0



This may have a minor issue, did not check. Test it and modify it.
def persistence(n, counter=0):
    if -10 < n < 10:
        return 0
    if n < 0:
        n *= -1
    result = 1
    while n > 9:
        last_digit = n % 10
        result *= last_digit
        n //= 10

    counter += 1
    if result > 9:
        return persistence(result, counter + 1)
    return counter + 1


print(persistence(999))
print(persistence(9999))
print(persistence(123456))
print(persistence(1))

print(persistence(-999))
print(persistence(-9999))
print(persistence(-123456))
print(persistence(-1))


Logic

Your code has logic issues. Logic bugs are among the most difficult "bugs". If you want to fully understand, put a print statement in each line.

Another way to solve the problem is to write multiple functions, so that each function does a specific task. You don't have to write the whole algorithm in one function.



No, the goal is not to multiply the digits. The goal is to how many times to multiply the digits of the number until you get to a one digit number. For example:

@cydar2500 I see. updated for that. You can modify the code if you don't have negative numbers.

999 -> 9 * 9 * 9 = 729
729 -> 7 *2 *9 = 126
126 -> 1 *2 *6 = 12
12 -> 1 * 2 = 2
See? It takes four iterations to get from 999 to 2 which is a single digit number. So I want my function to return 4 which is the number of iteration to get to a one digit number but returns 2.

@cydar2500 Edit your question with your comments. Also add some inputs and the expected outputs in the question.

@cydar2500 I see... have to go now, but you can modify the code now to do that. Right?

yes. I know there are other ways to do it. Thanks for your answer. But I don't know where lies the problem in my own code.

Thank you so much. It was helpful. But can you please tell me how come doesn't the code end here?(showed you in the stdin box using two checkboxes)

@cydar2500 Why should it stop? See here

Your program contains not just one mistake, so there is no one problem I could point you to.
The overarching problem appears to be that you are confusing the two parts of the program while doing the recursive calls. The two parts being:

calculating the product
counting how often you need to calculate the product

The result should actually be a product, but you start it with 0 and add to it as if it were a sum or counter, while for a product you would start with 1 and multiply onto it.
def persistence(n):
    if 0 <= n <= 9: 
        return n   # should definitely be 0, not n
    else:
        result = 0
        counter = 0
        while True:
            # Why add the product to something?
            # Should determine product here, not recursively call ourself
            result += n % 10 * persistence(n // 10)

            # No idea what we are doing, so no idea what we are counting
            counter += 1

            if result > 9:
                n = result
                result = 0
                continue
            return counter

print(persistence(999))  # Output should be 4 but gives me 2

What is actually executed is the following:
persistence(999) = ...
  persistence(99) = ...
    persistence(9) = ...
    persistence(9) = 9
    persistence(8) = ...
    persistence(8) = 8
  persistence(99) = 2
  persistence(1) = ...
  persistence(1) = 1
persistence(999) = 2

That is wrong on so many levels that it is difficult to fix step by step.
You can easily have both a product and a persistence function defined recursively, so let's see if we can start from there and approach the problem from the other side.
def product(n):
    if 0 <= n <= 9:
        return n
    return (n%10) * product(n//10)

def persistence(n):
    if 0 <= n <= 9:
        return 0
    return 1 + persistence(product(n))

but both of those are very different functions from the persistence function you have written. What is actually executed here:
persistence(999) = ...
  product(999) = ...
    product(99) = ...
      product(9) = ...
      product(9) = 9
    product(99) = 81
  product(999) = 729
  persistence(729) = ...
    product(729) = ...
      product(72) = ...
        product(7) = ...
        product(7) = 7
      product(72) = 14
    product(729) = 126
    persistence(126) = ...
      product(126) = ...
        product(12) = ...
          product(1) = ...
          product(1) = 1
        product(12) = 2
      product(126) = 12
      persistence(12) = ...
        product(12) = ...
          product(1) = ...
          product(1) = 1
        product(12) = 2
        persistence(2) = ...
        persistence(2) = 0
      persistence(12) = 1
    persistence(126) = 2
  persistence(729) = 3
persistence(999) = 4

It is easy to convert the recursion in each of those two functions into a while loop each. That removes the potential for stack enlargement, but it does not necessarily improve readability:
def product(m):
    prod = 1
    while m > 0:
        prod *= m%10
        m //= 10
    return prod

def persistence(n):
    counter = 0
    while n > 9:
        n = product(n)
        counter += 1
    return counter

However, integrating the functionality of those two functions into one function only makes things more confusing with the extra variable(s):
def persistence(n):
    counter = 0
    while n > 9:
        m = n
        prod = 1
        while m > 0:
            prod *= m%10
            m //= 10
        n = prod
        counter += 1
    return counter

OK, we can get rid of one more variable by re-using n, but that does not help with readability either:
def persistence(n):
    counter = 0
    while n > 9:
        m = n
        n = 1
        while m > 0:
            n *= m%10
            m //= 10
        counter += 1
    return counter

Note how your program mixes one while loop with recursion, while you actually need two nested while loops or two recursive functions with one calling the other, or one while loop inside one recursive function, or one recursive function inside one while loop.
Mixing recursion and a while loop does not do useful work here.
